# Oauth2 client + user access tokens flow

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using Oauth2 php library. I've followed the docs [here](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/client-credentials/) and [here](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/user-credentials/)
This is what I have so far:

- a client application requests a token using client id & client secret
  to the client_credential end point
- a token is returned to the client app with a basic scope
- a user logs in from the client app
- the client application requests a new token using user id & user
  password to the user_credential end point
- the client app receive a new token with the new scope of the user

Everything works.

The only thing that doesn't make sense to me is that I have to pass again the client id & client secret when doing the user authorization (grant_type:'password') otherwise  wise it doesn't work.

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials were not found in the headers or body"}

My understanding was that since I obtained first a client token, I wouldn't have to identify the client again. I've tried passing the token instead of client id & client password for user auth but no go. What's the proper grant type combination for what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (single) client is either `public`, i.e. it has no `client_secret` associated with it, or `confidential` i.e. it uses a `client_secret` to identify itself. It cannot be both at the same time. What you could do is register a second client with a different `client_id` as a public client, so it won't have to use a `client_secret` to identify itself to the Authorization Server. You could then use that second `client_id` from your (single) client app in the second part of the desired flow.